# How to get enabled sign in method from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to get list of enabled sign method(like facebook, google,twitter) from Firebase, so i can that show dynamically that option in login?

[this is sign in method that i have enabled in firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/275EN.png)

```
public void createSignInIntent() {
    // [START auth_fui_create_intent]
    // Choose authentication providers
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build());
    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)// for auto login
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.logo_top)      // Set logo drawable
                    .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                    .build(),
            REQ_FIREBASE_LOGIN);
    // [END auth_fui_create_intent]
}
```

I need to pass `AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER` and `AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER` dynamically. For example if i disable google login in Firebase console then it don't want to show in my login screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can get programmatically the sign-in methods that you have enabled manually in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). You can just enable them manually and according to what options you have selected, you can then implement the code accordingly.

If you are implementing the code for example for Facebook but you haven't enabled the Facebook sign-in option, you'll get an error related to insufficient permissions.